# SQL - returning values when a condition is met for that value over two or more rows

Tags: sql, database, group-by, uniqueidentifier

I’ve got two data tables -

Order level:

```
Order_number | order total | etc
Order_num1   | $10
Order_num2   | $20
```

And line-item level:

```
Order_number | sku  | quantity | etc    
Order_num1   | sku1 | 3    
Order_num1   | sku2 | 2    
Order_num2   | sku1 | 4
```

And so on.

I am trying to write a query that returns any Order_numX that contains both skuY and skuZ.

Im thinking about somehow grouping the line item table but I’m not sure.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select order_number
from line_item
where sku in (?, ?)
group by order_number
having count(distinct sku) = 2;  -- number of items in list
```

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest you to using `EXISTS` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM line-item
             WHERE line-item.Order_number=Order.Order_number
             AND line-item.sku='skuY'
             )
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM line-item
             WHERE line-item.Order_number=Order.Order_number
             AND line-item.sku='skuZ'
             )
```

This query gives you the orders which have both `skuY` and `skuZ` values of `sku` column of child table, which here is `line-item`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Order_number 
FROM line_item 
GROUP BY Order_number 
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN sku = skuY THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT( CASE WHEN sku = skuZ THEN 1 END) > 0
```